# Get Keys and Value from a single row SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get the keys and the values from a single row...

here's my code :

```
$tab_titres_fr=array();
$sql="SELECT * FROM recettes  WHERE recetteid = '$id' ";
$request = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($request);
$tab_titres_fr[]=json_encode($row);    

foreach($tab_titres_fr as $key => $value) {

    echo   $keys." / ".$value."<br>" ;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the query returns a result? Perhaps you can print the number of entries or try the query using a visual database management tool...

Comment: Furthermore replace `$keys` with `$key`.

Comment: is this based upon some example code? You seem to be missing a loop. Also "$key" and "$keys" - weird

Answer (score 0):

```
$request = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($request)){
$tab_titres_fr[]=json_encode($row);
}
foreach($tab_titres_fr as $key => $value) {

echo   $key." / ".$value."<br>" ;
}
```

Comment: I didn't loop it for I have to read just one row, but I still don't have isolate values. I have {"recetteid":"12","username":"stoker",etc... How can I get $Keys=recetteid and $value=12 etc...

Comment: I have this :{"recetteid":"12","username":"stoker","titre":"Abricot R\u00e9glisse","tauxnicpg":"6","tauxnicvg" etc....